# How to get sum, averages etc. from a nested array of numbers in documents in Couchdb

Tags: arrays, mapreduce, nested, couchdb

I have a CouchDB database with documents which contain data like:

```
"field1": "text",
"field2": "text",
"field3":[14 54 23 24,25,26,23,19,17 etc.]
etc.
```

I am trying to do a map reduce to get an average of all the field3 values in the database.

I have done a map as follows:

```
function(doc) {
if(doc.field3){
emit(null,doc.field3);
}
}
```

and a reduce:

```
function (keys, values, rereduce) {
if (rereduce){
return sum(values);
} else {
return values.length;
}
}
```

or simply:

```
_sum
```

The latter gives a range of numbers which seems to be a sum of identical numbers in the arrays.

There was an example on the Cloudant site which touched on accessing an array of numbers but was not the complete answer, and I can't find it at the moment.

I have also investigated the new `'mango'`query system on CouchDB 2.0.0 which is much easier to set up but I don't see in the documentation any way of doing calculations with it.

**EDIT**

Permit me the liberty to add to this question with a good example perhaps.

I am using [Mockaroo](https://www.mockaroo.com) to generate data and found an alternative method to generate this data that was more realistic because I could vary more aspects of the data.

However this resulted in the following change to my array:

```
"field3":[{"item": 44}, {"item":23}, {"item": 36}, etc.]
```

Using the successful map provided by `@Alexis` I tried to get it to read this data. Example:

```
function(doc) {
if(doc.field3[0].item >0){
if (doc.field3) {
    if (Array.isArray(doc.field3))
        for (var n in doc.field3)
            emit(null, doc.field3[n].item);
}
}
}
```

I tried numerous variations of the above code, adding `.item` or `[]` and adding/removing if statements, without success.

I would appreciate help with this variation of the array as well, if possible.

Setting up javascript in map/reduce is not easy for some reason.
I have been through quite a few free online javascript learning courses to try and improve my abilities with CouchDB, without much success.
Is there a better way to learn the dark art of writing correct javascript for map reduce??

Many thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Your reduce is the equivalent of _count, not **_sum**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want the global average on field3 wich is an array, I would first map all the field 3 values and reduce them all.

Map function :

```
function(doc) {
    if (doc.field3) {
        if (Array.isArray(doc.field3))
            for (var n in doc.field3)
                emit(null, doc.field3[n]);
    }
}
```

Reduce function :

```
function(keys, values, rereduce) {
    return sum(values)/values.length;
}
```

**New edit means new answer!**

```
//Your function

function(doc) {
    if (doc.field3[0].item > 0) {
        if (doc.field3) {
            if (Array.isArray(doc.field3))
                for (var n in doc.field3)
                    emit(null, doc.field3[n].item);
        }
    }
}

//Fixed one

function(doc){
    //We check if the field3 is an array and we check if its length is 
    //true. In javascript 0==false, any number ==true  and the length can't 
    // be negative so we are in business.
    if(Array.isArray(doc.field3) && doc.field3.length){ 
        //Your array contains many object. So we can simply iterate through them
        for(var i=0;i<doc.field3.length;i++){
            //at this point, doc.field3[i] is one of the object. Eg: {"item":44}
            emit(null,doc.field3[i].item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly @Alexis. Please see Edits above if you will allow me the liberty to add to my question.

Comment: @jlb333333 If you want to have a better understanding of your function, you could use a debugger that let's you see the variable in real time. To do so, query your database and limit the query to 10 documents just so it's not too heavy. Then convert the data to JSON and start working on a JavaScript environment.  

The javascript in the views are pretty simple but hard to debug. In general, you only need to know how to iterate through objects,arrays and to compare/validate values.